# android studio only checks and retrieve the last added value in firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create an application where I need to get the availability of a WC from the firebase database,
The problem however is that the android studio only checks the last added item, and brings me its status,

This is my code

```
 DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Bathrooms");
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {



            for ( DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                 Bathrooms bathrooms = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Bathrooms.class);
                bathroomsArrayList.add(bathrooms);

            }

            Browse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if(bathrooms.getAvailability().equals("Yes")&&bathrooms.getFloor().equals(Floor.getSelectedItem())&&bathrooms.getSection().equals(Section.getSelectedItem())){

                        disable.setChecked(true);
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Browse done successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                    else {
                        disable.setChecked(false);
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No bathrooms", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    }

                }
            });





        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Opsss.... Something is wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

return rootview;

```
}
```

And this is a picture of the firebase where the data is in

[image: firebase]

I am not using an arrayadapter, because I want the data to be updated constantly since I will be using a sensor.

Comment: What do you mean through "only checks the last added item"?

Comment: Hello thank you for replying, 
Based on my if else statement, I want to check all the items inside the firebase child "bathrooms" and get any statement with a "YES" in availability, however I only get the last item in the database, 
It's like the if else go through the entire firebase but only return the last item added to the firebase..

Comment: And you want to get them all?

Comment: yes exactly, I think the problem might be with Bathroom bathroom being "final" however I don't know how to change the final because I can't declare it as a non-final inside the button.

Comment: If you want to get them all, add them to a list.

Comment: hello Alex could u please check my code after adding an array it's still doesn't work, I edit the question

Answer (score 0):

this work for you
replace users white name Database Head

```
myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                Log.d("rrr", "onDataChange0: ");
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot:snapshot.getChildren())
                Log.d("rrr", "onDataChange: "+dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, May I ask what is Log.d?

Comment: for print message in logcat

Comment: thanks again but it still doesn't work
I still receive only the info from the last added item on firebase

Comment: sorry could u elaborate more ? I didn't get it

Comment: You have to create the shape of your database in this way and give the name of the database master here as the user

Comment: I don't think the issue with the database as it works good on other modules, I don't know why here it only shows me the last added item